# Text Field doesn't active for Static Cell in Table View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have Single View App for IOS Xcode 6.4. Example [Add Player](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2) screen, I tried it by myself, but Text Field doesn't active to click and typing at my application simulator (UITableViewController Static Cell) I have compared my project with example final project, everything looks good similar. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried cmd+k ?

Answer (score 0):

First you try with cmd+k that will open the simulator's keyboard. If that is not working then try with cmd+shit+k that may hide your keyboard but you can able to type on the text filed. If that also not work then you may accidentally off the user interaction for text field. Or may be some other view covering your text field which is transparent, so you are not able to see it. I hope that will save your problem, otherwise please provide your code sample.

Comment: Located header position and doesn't active, what happen? You can see on this: http://pho.to/9grey

Comment: @B.Gunduz did you set the correct height for header in section? also PLAYER NAME is place holder or label?

Comment: I didn't set anything like height etc. I did Table View: Static Cell, Style: Grouped. In addition, PLAYER NAME is Table View Section, Header Title. It is not drag item label. I have added a new photo: http://pho.to/9grjJ

Comment: Whatever I think according to you screen shot, you have not set the row height properly. Thats why problem creating. Try to setup the height of the row and section header properly. I think that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  bug in the segue transition. Set the transition to None and it should work. I had the problem with a Curl transition.